# How to pass parameter to soap web service using webservice consumer in anypoint

Tags: anypoint-studio

Can anyone give me an example how we can pass parameter to webservice if we are using ws:consumer in Anypoint Studio.

```
 <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer1" operation="login" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
```

i have to pass object parameter to login method of web service as we do it in java

```
LoginParam lp = new LoginParam("key","pwd");
LoginResponseParam lrp = port.login(lp);
```

Comment: Did you get a solution? I am to need resolve this problem too.

Comment: No i am still stuck at the same.